# Join two lines in a text file in Unix based on regex pattern matching by removing the newline character in between

Tags: regex, unix, replace, sed, find

I want to do the following Find & Replace operation to a file in Unix

```
Find:   (\n)(^[^T])
Replace:  \t$2
```

For example,

```
Time table
DataColumn
```

becomes

```
Time table     DataColumn
```

This works in a text editor like TextPad, but, is there any way to do this in a single line command? For example, something like:

```
sed 's/\(\n\)\(^[^T]\)/\t\2/g' tmpfile2.txt
```

Comment: So you just want to replace a newline sequence with tab?

Comment: Yes, but not all of them, only those newline characters that come before a line that doesn't start with 'T'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/\n\([^T]\)/\t\1/;P;D' file
```

This replaces a newline followed by a non `T` character by a tab and the non `T` character throughout the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -0pe 's/\n/\t/' file
Time table      DataColumn
```

Comment: This is nice, I should definitely learn perl. +1 for efficient and elegant scripting!

Comment: I think you missed the regex part?

Comment: Do you have any error ? What the output looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Since sed and perl have been suggested, here comes awk:

```
awk '/^T/{value=$0; getline; $0= value "\t" $0;} {print}'
```